# Trigger vs Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

Does a trigger have a better performance over a stored procedure considering both have same block of code?

Trigger is invoked implicitly. Does this have any impact on performance?

Comment: What is the question given that the behavior is different. How do you FORCE a SP to be used? a Trigger and a SP have totally different targets.

Comment: Functionally both differs from each other. Check this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/624566/Differences-between-a-Stored-Procedure-and-a-Trigg

Comment: It seems your question is related to performance rather than functionality.  There are cases where you could user either a proc or trigger to implement a given requirement.  I would expect a trigger to be slightly slower due to maintaining the row version store for the inserted and deleted pseudo tables but you will need to test in your actual situation.

Comment: Often a stored proc doing the action directly along with the update,delete,insert would be more efficient than doing it in a trigger. The advantage of a trigger is that it fires for all modifications, not just those managed through your procedure.

Comment: I would say both are different and have there own field. You need to produce specific scenario. I also consider question as too open and seems more like discussion

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a simple answer as it depends on what you are doing in the code block for example a simple update to a column in the table for the trigger (updating a update date column as an example) wouldn't probably benefit from being in a stored procedure however for more complex code sql could use parameter sniffing to cache the execution plans but even the performance gains from this can be [negated](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) and i'm pretty sure unless you were dynamically building queries in the trigger sql will cache plans from triggers anyway so maybe you wouldn't see any difference at all (i'm not 100% sure about that though).

As a trigger and a stored proc are not functionally the same you would still need a trigger to execute the stored proc unless you relied on application code to call the stored proc after certain events (never do this) so a trigger would still be involved anyway.

The main reason i would use a stored proc inside a trigger would be to avoid duplicate code and make the code more modular, i think you would mainly see noticeable performance improvements from stored procs when replacing ad hoc queries in application code.

Answer (score 1):

They don't have the same block of code, and they do different things. So it's difficult to compare.

A trigger and a SP that both just do `SELECT 1` would probably be effectively identical.

Given a repeatedly called procedure that processes every row in a huge (but seldom changed) table vs a trigger that only operates on INSERTED rows, the trigger would obviously be better because it does a lot less work

Given a stored procedure that creates indexes and runs once a day vs a trigger that creates indexes every time a row is changed, the SP would be 'better'